# Почему не фильтрует по индексу?

Tags: javascript, filter

Вот как выглядит переменная sort
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь сортировать по индекс, result получается пустой массив

```js
var sort= [{
  "car": "Pontiac",
  "id": 1
}, {
  "car": "Mitsubishi",
  "id": 2
}, {
  "car": "Toyota",
  "id": 3
}, {
  "car": "Lexus",
  "id": 4
}, {
  "car": "GMC",
  "id": 5
}, {
  "car": "Mazda",
  "id": 6
}, {
  "car": "Saturn",
  "id": 7
}, {
  "car": "Scion",
  "id": 8
}, {
  "car": "Volkswagen",
  "id": 9
}, {
  "car": "Pontiac",
  "id": 10
}];

console.log(sort);
let reuslt = '';
result = sort.filter(index => {
  return index > 2 && index < 4;
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Что, по-вашему, должно попадать в переменную `index` внутри `filter()`?

Comment: index элемента в массиве

Comment: А это мнение на чем-то основано? Вообще-то `filter` работает не так: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Ну и в данном конкретном случае, вам нужен не `filter()`, а `slice()`

Comment: Ну там написано что есть параметр index

Comment: Угу, есть, вот только это не первый, а **второй** параметр callback-функции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) принимает функцию со следующей сигнатурой:

```
function (element, index, sourceArray)
```

В примере, передается функция с одним параметром, так как параметры позиционные, а не именованные, то значением внутри функции будет все тот же элемент массива, а не его индекс.

Чтобы использовать индекс, нужно использовать второй параметр:

```js
var sort = [{
  "car": "Pontiac",
  "id": 1
}, {
  "car": "Mitsubishi",
  "id": 2
}, {
  "car": "Toyota",
  "id": 3
}, {
  "car": "Lexus",
  "id": 4
}, {
  "car": "GMC",
  "id": 5
}, {
  "car": "Mazda",
  "id": 6
}, {
  "car": "Saturn",
  "id": 7
}, {
  "car": "Scion",
  "id": 8
}, {
  "car": "Volkswagen",
  "id": 9
}, {
  "car": "Pontiac",
  "id": 10
}];

let result = '';
result = sort.filter((_, index) => index > 2 && index < 4);
console.log(result);
```